# Need to act on a Silverlight RadioButton when it has been databound

Tags: silverlight

I'm creating a custom RadioButton that has some additional functionality. I need to somehow subscribe to an "OnDataBound" event - is there such a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there. OnDataBound of what property? All or just something specific?

Comment: When IsChecked is bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way i can think of:

1) Create a UserControl that encapsulates a `RadioButton` with a `DependencyProperty` that holds a `CustomIsChecked` object:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomRadioButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomRadioButton : UserControl
    {
        public CustomRadioButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        #region CustomIsChecked
        public bool CustomIsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(CustomDataContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CustomDataContextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CustomIsChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomIsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CustomIsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomRadioButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((dpo, dpce) => 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("IsChecked has changed!");
            })));
        #endregion
    }
```

In the XAML part of the `UserControl`, bind the `IsChecked` of your `RadioButton` to the `CustomIsChecked`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CustomRadioButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CustomIsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
</UserControl>
```

voila!

Comment: Let me try this out soon and get back to you. You might have solved a lot of issues for me!

Comment: this.DataContext = this;?? Not this.DataContext = CustomDataContext?

Comment: Yes, I'm also pretty sure you can omit it. CustomDataContext is only meant for the inner RadioButton

Comment: I just saw you commented on your question that you wanted to act on IsChecked. you'd have to declare the dependencyproperty as boolean, and bind the IsChecked property of your inner RadioButton instead of its DataContext.

Comment: > and bind the IsChecked property of your inner RadioButton - What do you mean by that?

Comment: What's the different between using the CustomIsChecked approach and the DataContext approach you previously posted?

Comment: It's the same difference as setting the DataContext of a Radiobutton or just its IsChecked property. It is good practice to try and bind only what's stricly necessary, otherwise your bindings will update more often than they need.

Comment: OK. I was playing around with your first approach but does it require me to specify the CustomDataContext on each instance instead of just setting it on the parent container?

Comment: This discussion led me to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38559/Silverlight-DataContext-Changed-Event, which solved my problems. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeC. You will have to bind the IsChecked property each time you use a CustomRadioButton in your XAML.